# submitting jobs to a Linux workstation

Tags: c++, linux

I have access to some Linux Workstations on which I run my 
C++ executable files from my Laptop but the problem is that 
each time I run a job from the terminal in my laptop I have 
to keep a terminal window for each job ... I need a way to 
submit the job to the Linux machine and see the result once 
only after the execution finishes ... I know that this can 
be done in FORTRAN executable by adding & at the end only and
I tried it with:
mpirun -np 20 ./a 200 1000000&
and
mpirun -np 20 ./a 200 1000000 &
but non of them is working ...

Is there anyway to do the same in Linux with C++ ??

Comment: Have you looked at nohup?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `nohup` at the beginning of the command. This will protect the process from the `SIGHUP` signal (which can indicate that the owning terminal was closed), the default action for which is to terminate the process.  For example:

```
nohup mpirun -np 20 ./a 200 1000000 &
```

Comment: Absolutely correct :).  You know about the "&" part (to run the program in the background).  "nohup" keeps your program from getting killed when you log off your terminal session.  Finally, you might also wish to redirect output to a file you can read later: `nohup mpirun -np 20 ./a 200 1000000 2>&1 mylog.txt &`

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `screen` command.

```
man 1 screen
```

Comment: Unfortunately, "screen" probably won't help the OP if he wants to kill his terminal session.  I believe "nohup" is the command he's looking for.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 I believe he means to run the command inside of screen. Then the terminal can exit after detaching from the screen instance, and the program will continue to run inside of screen, where it can be reattached to later.

Comment: screen will run detached, and you can reattach to it -- and OP did say he wants to see the results when it's done